# How can I make Google's blogger a PWA(progressive web app)

Tags: progressive-web-apps, blogger

I mean to say how to add service workers in the Blogspot theme editor. I tried to add an external JavaScript but didn't work. Please tell me a way how to add a folder or similar to a folder in the Blogspot theme.

Answer (score 2):

Up to this point, it's impossible there was the question asked to Google:

https://support.google.com/blogger/thread/3184773?hl=en

And these are their answers:

[image: answer1]

[image: answer2]

You can consider it as I did to request the feature.